# Decorator and Inheritance with parameters

Tags: python, inheritance, parameters, decorator

There is a decorator with inheritance. It works well:

```
class bar(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val

    @staticmethod
    def decor(func):
        def increment(obj, x):
            return func(obj, x) + obj.val
        return increment

class foo(bar):
    def __init__(self):
        bar.__init__(self)

    @bar.decor
    def add(self, x):
        return x
```

But I want to add a parameter in the `class foo`:

```
class foo(bar):
    def __init__(self,B):
        bar.__init__(self)
        self.B = B
```

And I want to input `B` into the decorator as an parameters, I've tried a scratch:

```
class bar(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val

    @staticmethod
    def decor(B):
        def wrap(func):
            def increment(obj, x):
                return func(obj, x) + obj.val + B
            return increment
        return wrap

class foo(bar):
    def __init__(self,B):
        bar.__init__(self)
        self.B = B

    @bar.decor(B)
    def add(self, x):
        return x
```

But it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where would you get the `B` from in the `@bar.decor(B)` decoration?

Comment: In the `__init__()` method for `class foo(bar)`, where does the variable named `B` used on the right-hand side of the assignment in the statement `self.B = B` come from?

Comment: What you attempt to do seems impossible. The decorators are all executed at import time, as soon as the methods are defined. They do not wait until an instance of a class is instantiated. Therefore, they cannot depend on the values passed to the `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class bar(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    @staticmethod
    def decor(func):
        def increment(obj, x):
            return func(obj, x) + obj.val + obj.B
        return increment

class foo(bar):
    def __init__(self,val,B):
        bar.__init__(self,val)
        self.B = B

    @bar.decor
    def add(self, x):
        return x

aa = foo(4, 1.5)
a = aa.add(1)
print(a)
```

Comment: Could you please add at least a brief explanation what you did here? It looks almost like a verbatim copy of the first part of the question, with the difference that an additional `+ obj.B` appears in the inner `increment` function.

Comment: I just want to create a decorator to work on the function of ‘class foo’ which is inherited from 'class bar' and with its own parameter B as one part of the decorator.